# How can I re-build Mail.app's search index?

Tags: macos, mail.app

Since upgrading to Lion, my search in Mail has gotten drastically less helpful. Since I have read many reviews about what an improvement Mail 5.0's search is, I can only assume that my search index was not built correctly. Is there a file I can delete or a terminal command I can run to tell Mail to re-index my messages?

Comment: Is the search slow? The improvements are more along the lines of filtering with what Apple calls "tokens".

Comment: No, I searched something that I knew without a doubt existed, and it never showed up. It just plain 'ol didn't find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mail keeps a sqlite database of the index. To rebuild it, delete the index and restart Mail.

```
rm -f ~/Library/Mail/V2/MailData/Envelope\ Index
```

Comment: Mail is re-importing all of my messages as we speak. I have a feeling this is going to be the fix. When I first launched Mail 5.0 I had an incompatible plugin installed and I think Mail's warning me of that caused the importing of mailboxes to stop short.

Comment: Note: running this command will wipe out your local cache of mail messages and require Mail.app to re-download everything.  If all you want to do is rebuild your search index, see the mdutil command provided by aaltonen

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I've used in the past to rebuild the search index:

```
sudo mdutil -E /
```

The -E option "will cause each local store for the volumes indicated to be erased. The stores will be rebuilt if appropriate."

While I don't use Mail.app, I noticed similar behavior with Outlook 2011 -- which also uses Spotlight for search.